# Is it possible to create an AutoKeys macro with VBA in Access?

Tags: ms-access, macros, vba

In an Access application, I'd like to programmatically set up a dynamic key handler to execute a VBA function when this key is pressed.

I was able to manually create a macro that calls the function and another *AutoKeys* macro that "calls" the first macro when a specific key is pressed.

Now, I'd like to be able to create these macros with VBA only. Is this somehow possible?

Of course, if there are other ways to achieve what I want, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: If you have open forms, you can use KeyPress event in forms for calling global key handler

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to have the macro called irrespective if and what form is opened.

Comment: I don't think you can. There are `Application.CreateForm` and `Application.CreateReport`, but nothing alike for macros. `CurrentDb.Containers("Scripts").Documents` gets you all existing macros, but you can't add through that.

Comment: I think you can look at API function RegisterHotKey. At least [V6 allows to register](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBRegisterHotkey-50af3179/sourcecode?fileId=22123&pathId=998247884) hot key for current application. You can register it to hidden form

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, create a class called clsCustomForm, containing this code

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents frmCustomForm As Form

Public Function INIT(frmFormToMakeCustom As Form)
    Set frmCustomForm = frmFormToMakeCustom
    frmCustomForm.OnKeyDown = "[Event Procedure]"
End Function

Private Sub frmCustomForm_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Then in a module, you will need to have a public collection, which you add a class for each form opened and removed when each form closed, I'd suggest a dictionary, with the key as the form name and the item as the class, for example, just testing (limited time) I've used the following code in 1 form, hope this helps, i'll have a bit more time later to show the dictionary if needed.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public CUSTOM_FORM As clsCustomForm

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set CUSTOM_FORM = New clsCustomForm
   CUSTOM_FORM.INIT Me
End Sub
```